# How to change all external links to "nofollow" but only for Contributor role?

Tags: links, nofollow

Is there a way that I can change all my current (and future created) links to nofollow created by Contributor and leave all links "follow" created by the Administrator or Editor.

Comment: Is this for new posts created via Posts > Add New?

Comment: For all posts that are already published and for future created posts.

Comment: Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score -1):

I am exactly looking for this question
I have found these codes to convert all links to Nofallow, can anyone change these codes according to the user's role

https://www.codespeedy.com/relnofollow-for-all-external-links-in-wordpress-using-code/

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/249059)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).